# Function expects 2 arguments when should only one

Tags: python, django, function, argument-passing

I have a function `friend_exists` like this:

```
def friend_exists(request, pid):
    result = False
    try:
        user = Friend.objects.get(pid=pid)
    except Friend.DoesNotExist:
        pass  
    if user:
        result = True

    return result
```

I'm calling it from my other function like this:

```
exists = friend_exists(form.cleaned_data['pid'])
```

where `pid = u'12345678'`. Why I'm getting:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /user/register/
Exception Value: friend_exists() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: pls fix post's title typo funciotn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you think it should only take one? You've clearly got two arguments in the function definition:

```
def friend_exists(request, pid):
```

Right there it says it expects `request` and `pid`.

Comment: If that's the actual source for the `friend_exists` function, it doesn't look like the `request` argument is needed.  Maybe that one argument is some accidental holdover after refactoring (or something)?

Comment: I just thought request is automatically populated

Answer (score 2):

It takes two arguments and you are only giving it one, the value of form.cleaned_data['pid']. If that value is actually a tuple/list of the two arguments, you want to expand it with the asterisk like:

```
exists = friend_exists(*form.cleaned_data['pid'])
```

A cleaner approach in that case might then be:

```
request, pid = form.cleaned_data['pid']
exists = friend_exists(request, pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like django, so the way to properly call your function would be `friend_exists(request, form.cleaned_data['pid']`. When a view function is called, the request is automatically populated, so it may seem like that should happen for every call in a django app, but as you are calling the function manually, you will have to manually pass it the `request` object.